# IE7 Times Out Debugging ASP.Net Page

Tags: asp.net, debugging, internet-explorer-7

My issue is similar to [ASP.NET Debugging Timing out with IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741439/asp-net-debugging-timing-out-with-iis) except that I'm using the built-in ASP.Net Development Server with VS 2010.

If I pause for more than about 10 seconds in the debugger, IE7 "disconnects" from the web server with the error message

> Internet Explorer cannot display the
>   webpage

However, unlike in the similar question, the debugger is still running.  If I refresh the browser it will post that refresh to the server and I can debug the page from the top again.

Is it possible to configure things so that IE7 waits (much) longer before giving up?

If it makes a difference, I'm launching IE using the "Start external program" option and passing a localhost URL as the command line argument (since Chrome is my default browser).  I also specify a specific port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution

> Add a **ReceiveTimeout** DWORD entry with
>   a value of ()*1000
>   in the following registry subkey:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings For example, if you want the
>   time-out duration to be 8 minutes, set
>   the value of the ReceiveTimeout entry
>   to 480000 (<480>*1000).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q181050/