# IIS Request Timeout on long ASP.NET operation

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, httprequest

I am experiencing a request timeout from IIS when I run a long operation. Behind the scene my ASP.NET application is processing data, but the number of records being processed is large, and thus the operation is taking a long time.

However, I think IIS times out the session. Is this a problem with IIS or ASP.NET session?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

If you want to extend the amount of time permitted for an ASP.NET script to execute then increase the [`Server.ScriptTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout.aspx) value. The default is 90 seconds for .NET 1.x and 110 seconds for .NET 2.0 and later.

For example:

```
// Increase script timeout for current page to five minutes
Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
```

This value can also be configured in your `web.config` file in the [`httpRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=VS.80).aspx) configuration element:

```
<!-- Increase script timeout to five minutes -->
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" 
  ... other configuration attributes ...
/>
```

[image]

Please note according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> "This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation
>   element is False. Therefore, if the debug attribute is True, you do
>   not have to set this attribute to a large value in order to avoid
>   application shutdown while you are debugging."

If you've already done this but are finding that your session is expiring then increase the 
ASP.NET [`HttpSessionState.Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=VS.80).aspx) value:

For example:

```
// Increase session timeout to thirty minutes
Session.Timeout = 30;
```

This value can also be configured in your `web.config` file in the `sessionState` configuration element:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If your script is taking several minutes to execute and there are many concurrent users then consider changing the page to an [Asynchronous Page](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/12/427318.aspx). This will increase the scalability of your application.

The other alternative, if you have administrator access to the server, is to consider this long running operation as a candidate for implementing as a scheduled task or a windows service.

Comment: FYI httpRuntime executionTimeout is in seconds and has no uppercase T

Comment: It is also important to note that debug mode be set to false in order for this timeout value to be used: <system.web><compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/></system.web>

Comment: @JesseRoper if you can point me to the docs on that then I'd be happy to include that in the answer, or you could edit my answer directly. Ta.

Comment: Default executionTimeout value is 110 seconds.

Comment: A brief bit of info on how a scheduled task or windows service would help would be nice.

Answer (score 23):

Great and exhaustive answerby @Kev!

Since I did long processing only in one admin page in a WebForms application I used the code option. But to allow a temporary quick fix on production I used the config version in a `<location>` tag in web.config. This way my admin/processing page got enough time, while pages for end users and such kept their old time out behaviour.

Below I gave the config for you Googlers needing the same quick fix. You should ofcourse use other values than my '4 hour' example, but **DO** note that the session `timeOut` is in minutes, while the request `executionTimeout` is in seconds!

And - since it's 2015 already - for a NON- quickfix you should use .Net 4.5's [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) now if at all possible, instead of the .NET 2.0's ASYNC page that was state of the art when KEV answered in 2010 :).

```
<configuration>
    ... 
    <compilation debug="false" ...>
    ... other stuff ..

    <location path="~/Admin/SomePage.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <sessionState timeout="240" />
            <httpRuntime executionTimeout="14400" />
        </system.web>
    </location>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have included the "location" snippet in my web.config but it is not working. I am using "executionTimeout" only, I don't need "sessionState". Do I have to configure something else.   I am using NET 4.0.  If I use "httpRuntime" directly in "system.web" it applies the time out correctly in all pages.

Answer (score 17):

I'm posting this here, because I've spent like 3 and 4 hours on it, and I've only found answers like those one above, that say do add the `executionTime`, but it doesn't solve the problem in the case that you're using **ASP .NET Core**. For it, this would work:

At web.config file, add the `requestTimeout` attribute at `aspNetCore` node.

```
<system.webServer>
  <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:10:00" ... (other configs goes here) />
</system.webServer>
```

In this example, I'm setting the value for 10 minutes.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/aspnet-core-module#configuring-the-asp-net-core-module

Comment: This applies only for `OutOfProcess` hosting model. For `InProcess` there is not timeout setting. IIS will keep waiting for the process to complete, reference here: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/16870

Answer (score -11):

Remove `~` character in location 
so

```
path="~/Admin/SomePage.aspx"
```

becomes

```
path="Admin/SomePage.aspx"
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question