# continuous stream on IIS server - will it crash and how can i best execute this code?

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, stream

I am currently developing a twitter streaming web app as part of a College proj. I have written code that uses curl to stream from twitter and writes the data to a sql server 2008 express database.

```
    ProcessStartInfo curl = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Process process = new Process();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        curl.FileName = @"c:\program files\Curl\curl.exe";
        curl.Arguments = "http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json -u username:password";
        curl.UseShellExecute = false;
        curl.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        process = Process.Start(curl);
        Twitter_Stream(sender, e);
    }
    protected void Twitter_Stream(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

        // Start curl process
        using (process)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                try
                {
                    // create connection and open connection
                    conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["strConnectionString"].ToString());
                    conn.Open();
                    // Post the output from curl to the queue.
                    // One line = one tweet in json format.
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        // create a SqlCommand object for this connection
                        SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                        command.CommandText = "save_stream";

                        string result = reader.ReadLine();
                        Message message = new Message(result);

                        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(message.Body.ToString());

                        /* I parse the obj here and exec query to save data
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { /*DO some error logging here.*/}

                finally
                {
                    // close the connection
                    conn.Close();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Twitter_Stream(sender, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

My question is, As i have put a while loop that will or should never end in my code, will this cause an issue on the server load. Will a continuous loop crash the server? Also what should I use instead?
Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not crash the server because IIS is already watching for this case.  If a page's [execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829202/iis-request-timeout-on-long-asp-net-operation) is greater than the currrent threshold, IIS will kill the thread.

Instead of making this a webpage, you should make this a console application.  You can use infinite loops as much as you want in those.

Comment: I agree with @David. The next step that most people take when they try to bypass the page-timeout is to create a background thread to do the work. This will also fail when the app pool eventually recycles.

Comment: Thanks guys, great help. I created a console app which I can run from the command line and it seems to be running smoothly. Thanks again.