# How to time out request/connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Recently, I've noticed that my website is getting hit by a crawler, which takes a very long time to open the pages. I never thought about it before but realized now that my MVC3 application never times out. For example, if I put in a `Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 10)` (ten minutes) in my controller action and I open the page, after 10 minutes I will get rendered view.

I've read tons of articles and SO questions but no luck. I tried the solutions below on both localhost, and production server with "Release" built, but none of those did what I wanted it to do.

Solution 1:

In web.config:

```
<location path="ControllerName/ActionName">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Solution 2:

In the controller action

```
HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 1;
```

The only idea I had left was to calculate the time that elapsed since the request came in and compare it to current time and if it's bigger than my timeout limit, throw and TimeoutException() manually. I planned to put it in "OnActionExecution" and "OnActionExecuted" but if the request gets stuck somewhere in between those, I will never be able to tell if I should time it out.

Is there a good solution to implement this? Did anyone ever get request timeout to work in MVC3?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why are your actions taking so long to begin with? Maybe that is something to improve on?

Comment: Actions work fine. But it looks like this crawler is slowing itself down on purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the timeout is a real problem here. I have a very strong suspicion that your site is hitting session locking issue, which is typical when being hammered by lots of simultaneous requests from the same source. Make sure you disable or mark session as readonly by default and only enable it on the actions where session is modified (like login controller for instance). See `SessionStateAttribute` for details.

Comment: Why do you think so? And what does it have to do with allowing one request to be alive for 'forever'

Comment: @bobek You running a crawler. Your pages suddenly take longer than expected. That is almost definitely session locking issue. It has **everything** to do with purposely blocking one of the requests. Other requests made by the same user (session) will be blocked until first one finishes.

Comment: @bobek Try simple experiment. Take 2 empty actions and add `Thread.Sleep(10000)` to the first one. Execute first one. Then execute second one in a different browser window. Observe that both are blocked. Now set the controller to "session state = readonly" and repeat. Observe that only first one is blocked.

Answer (score -1):

Good answer here:
[IIS Request Timeout on long ASP.NET operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829202/iis-request-timeout-on-long-asp-net-operation)

If you've already done this but are finding that your session is expiring then increase the ASP.NET HttpSessionState.Timeout value:

For example:

```
// Increase session timout to thirty minutes
Session.Timout = 30;
```

This value can also be configured in your web.config file in the sessionState configuration element:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```