# Why doesn't my action method time out?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http

I have the following controllers:

```
[TimeoutFilter]
public abstract class BaseController: Controller
{
}

public class IntegrationTestController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TimeoutSeconds()
    {
        return Content(HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ForceTimeout()
    {
        var timeoutWindow = TimeoutFilter.TimeoutSeconds;
        Thread.Sleep((timeoutWindow + 5) * 1000);
        return Content("This should never get returned, mwahahaaa!");
    }
}
```

For my test scenario I use a config setting of 5 seconds in the `TimeoutFilter`, and I know this is working because when my test calls `TimeoutSeconds`, I get the correct value of 5, but when the test calls `ForceTimeout`, I get an HTTP response of 200 and my 'never returned' text.

And the filter:

```
public class TimeoutFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    internal const string TimeoutSecondsSettingsKey = "MvcActionTimeoutSeconds";
    internal static int TimeoutSeconds;
    public TimeoutFilter()
    {
        TimeoutSeconds = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[TimeoutSecondsSettingsKey]);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = TimeoutSeconds;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your timeout filter implementation?

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama Added, as requested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I could not get this to work by setting the `ScriptTimeout` property either, even when setting the `debug="false"` in the `web.config` as suggested by user Erik Funkenbusch:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>
      ...
```

It continued to return the text "This should never get returned" rather than timing out during the `Thread.Sleep`.

It is also worth noting that I also extended the `Thread.Sleep` to well beyond the `Server.ScriptTimeout` default of 110 seconds but it still eventually returned the same text rather than timing out.

I then instead tried to set `executionTimeout` in the `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="5"/>
      ...
```

If you were to now add a breakpoint to the `TimeoutFilter` you will observe that the `ScriptTimeout` value has been set to the `executionTimeout` value from `web.config`.  Alas, this still did not work for me (regardless of whether `debug="false"`).

I then came across [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/334031-scripttimeout-executiontimeout-do-not-work) about `ScriptTimeout` and `executionTimeout` not working with a similar setup to what you describe.  The first reply in the post describes using the `debug="false"` and also mentions that the timeout will have a delay of 5 to 15 seconds.  I still had no luck even when using a large `Thread.Sleep` value.  The second reply in this article suggests that the `executionTimeout` config setting is a replacement of the `ScriptTimeout` property (which is apparently a COM interface used in classic ASP).  This reply suggests that is not possible to set a specific timeout without using your own time-out logic.

Further, I then came across the [following (more recent) link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1715081/4723882.aspx) where the first reply suggests that the timeout is switched off in MVC.  A further reply suggests that this is because an [`MVCHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchandler%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) (which selects the controller that will handle the `HTTPRequest`) is an `IHttpAsyncHandler` and as it may therefore be executing another request (which is the point of using an async request) it therefore internally switches the time-out state off (this is what I gather from reading this link).  It must work with straight `asp.net` though as using `ScriptTimeout` seems to be the accepted way in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829202/iis-request-timeout-on-long-asp-net-operation).

The link suggests that adding the following line will allow it to work (but not in a medium trust application):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetType().GetField("_timeoutState", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, 1);
```

Therefore, changing the `TimeoutFilter` `OnActionExecuting()` to:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetType().GetField("_timeoutState", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, 1);
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

and setting the `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="5"/>
      ...
```

allows the time-out to work but has the slight 5 second delay that is mentioned in the first post.

**Note**: Using this method does not allow you to set the `ScriptTimeout` property in the filter.  Trying to set `ScriptTimeout` and override the value set in `web.config` does not appear to work.

Comment: Indeed, good detective work.  Additionally, I found this connect report, which suggests a workaround (not a very good one, but if you can make it work, its better than nothing) https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781171/asp-net-mvc-executiontimeout-does-not-work

Answer (score 10):

<s>Are you using a debug build?</s>

From the ScriptTimeout documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

> If you set the debug attribute of the compilation element to true in the Web.config file, the value of ScriptTimeout will be ignored.

Also, since this value is the same as that set on the httpRuntime element, I really don't understand the point of this, since you can just configure that setting in in your web.config instead.

Edit:

Dangerous has done a good job of finding out the details, and indeed, ScriptTimeout is unsupported in asynchronous pipelines (which MVC has been since at least MVC4 I think, as well as WebApi.. even if not using async methods)

The "workaround" as suggested by this connect report:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781171/asp-net-mvc-executiontimeout-does-not-work

Use the `[AsyncTimeout]` attribute, and take a cancelation token as a parameter, then call `CanclationToken.ThrowIfCancelationRequested` periodically, or use the cancellation token in an async method.

Here's an example:

```
[AsyncTimeout(5000)]
public async Task<ContentResult> Index(CancellationToken ct)
{
    await Task.Delay(10 * 1000, ct);
    return Content("This should never get returned, mwahahaaa!");
}
```

This throws an OperationCanceled exception with a YSOD after 5 seconds.  The bonus for this is that it works even in Debug mode ;)

Comment: I am not sure of what the final config value be, after some reading about `machine.config` overriding the value, and the 'machine' is an Azure web site. This way I get to insist on a certain timeout value.

Comment: @ProfK - Why did you post a bounty when I gave you the answer?

Comment: Erik, as Dangerous notes above, changing the 'debug' attribute has no effect, on its own.

Comment: @ProfK - well, you failed to mention that you had even tried, much less that it did not work.  It might help if when people post an answer, you update them on whether or not the answer worked or not.

Comment: The link was a good find as there seems to be little documentation on this.  The [AsyncTimeout] method does work and is accurate when compared with using reflection (suggested in my answer) and does indeed have the added bonus of working in debug.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I hadn't tried when I first posted the question, nor even when I posted the bounty. I purely posted the bounty to literally attract more attention.