# ASP.NET executionTimeout not throwing

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to get execution timeouts working in ASP.NET MVC.

I have read that the execution timeout is only evaluated every 15s and only when `compilation debug="false"`, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/10/02/how-the-execution-timeout-is-managed-in-asp-net.aspx.

However I cant seem to get it to ever trigger a timeout.

I have a basic MVC application (off the template) and have made the following changes:

web.config:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="1" />
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20000);
        throw new Exception("Shouldnt get here as its longer than the execution timeout +15s");
    }
}
```

If the execution timeout is 1s and im sleeping for 20s in the controller it should always exceed the timeout (max of 16s), but when i run the application I always hit my exception.

**What do I need to do to get the thread to abort when it exceeds the timeout?**

Comment: I guess Thread.Sleep only pauses the execution for specified time it won't timeout as execution will start again after that time.

Comment: @MairajAhmad I changed the code to use a SpinWait and it still hits the exception, I think dehydration could cause it but prob only with async await.

Comment: Please check this link default timeout is 110 seconds. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @MairajAhmad but I've changed it in my web.config to 1s

Comment: @MairajAhmad Interestingly even if i wait for 125s (110 + 15) I still hit my exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78145/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-luke-mcgregor).

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Brian nah still don't know how to resolve this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my action method time out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170151/why-doesnt-my-action-method-time-out)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor: closed voted with a duplicate, hope the other link helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sleep does not work in this case.

You will need to make it do actual processing, like a for loop in a for loop doing something. For example:

```
var t = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; i++)
{
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 99999999; i2++)
    {
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 99999999; i2++)
        {
            t = i + i2 - i3;
        }
    }
}
```