# How to timeout a request in ASP.net MVC web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My application is running [ASP.Net MVC 5.2.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.2.2) and hosted on the IIS 7 integrated pipeline. I am looking to timeout requests when the duration of the request is over 3 minutes. Setting the [httpRuntime.executionTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/e1f13641(v=vs.80)) does not help.

I have other ASP.Net applications running in [IIS 6 classic mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7). Asp.Net automatically throws a `ThreadAbortException` when the request duration exceeds the `httpRuntime.executionTimeout` value.

I tried to look into the ASP.Net source code and found [RequestTimeoutManager](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/RequestTimeoutManager.cs). It basically keeps track of all the HttpRequests initialized and a background task aborts the requests exceeding the time out duration.  Is RequestTimeoutManager applicable for ASP.Net MVC Web Api? If not how can something similar be implemented.

Stack Trace for a typical Http Request in my application

```
   at MyApp.Api.Controllers.Controller.GetDetails(String Id) 
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3.<InvokeActionAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.Then[TOuterResult](Task task, Func`1 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<>c__DisplayClass3.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter.ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MyApp.Common.MyAppExceptionHandler.<>n__0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MyApp.Common.MyAppExceptionHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\MyApp_source\Components\MyAppExceptionHandler.cs
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at MyApp.Common.MyAppExceptionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

Comment: If using async-await then you can always use a cancellation token with your async code, you could also short circuit the request from a middleware as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom attribute to override timeout value in [AsyncManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.async.asyncmanager?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAsyncTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));
        }

        if (!(filterContext.Controller is IAsyncManagerContainer managerContainer))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Action Filter failed");
        }

        managerContainer.AsyncManager.Timeout = 180000;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Or why can't you use [[AsyncTimeout(180000)]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.asynctimeoutattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) ?

Comment: Setting the ScriptTimeout, executionTimeout, requestTimeout values does not work in MVC async pipelines. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27342836/1219543

Comment: Interesting. I changed answer. Maybe it will help you. Or are you looking for IIS side example

Answer (score 0):

You can **create a race between 2 running tasks**, *one for the main operation*, and *another for preferred timeout* (e.g 3 * 60,000 ms = 180,000 ms) by the following code :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get() 
{
    var _task = this.DoTask(2000); //your operation required time
    var _timeout = this.SetTimeout(180000); //equal to 3 minutes
    var _finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(_timeout, _task);
    if (_finishedTask == _timeout)
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout); //timeout
    else
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _task.Result); //Ok
}

private async Task<string> DoTask(int duration)
{
    await Task.Delay(duration);
    return "work results";
}

private async Task SetTimeout(int ms)
{
    await Task.Delay(ms);
}
```

I have tested with `ApiController` as base class and works fine. *The task which is finished earlier win the race and determines the Api result*.