# Why is my page is running for 10 minutes successfully?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, timeout

I have an asp.net mvc web application hosted in IIS and one of the pages sends e-mails to several inhouse employees. 
Sometimes this list can grow up to a hundred employees and each e-mail takes about 5 seconds.

I was expecting the page to timeout but it doesn't and I don't know why...
It just keeps on running for 10 minutes if neccesary and finishes successfully.

I have seen this post: [IIS Request Timeout on long ASP.NET operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829202/iis-request-timeout-on-long-asp-net-operation)

But there is nothing special in the web.config related to timeouts. I suspect this is a server setting somewhere.

Any guesses what this could be ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your SMTP config or if you use the `SmtpClient` to send the mails. But I think this operation takes to long.
I would recommend you to use a pickup directory and an SMTP relay to send the mails. This will speed up the performacance and removes this constraint from you application. This is an example of a pickup directory config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" deliveryFormat="SevenBit" from="example@example.com">
  <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" enableSsl="false" />
  <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\MailPickup" />
</smtp>
```