# The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway when fetching report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, timeout, bad-gateway

I have 2 servers, **Server A** contains ASP.net website and **Server B** contains SSRS. I have several reports that take long time to be fetched as data is big, now if I open these reports direct from SSRS **Server B** it take about 2 to 3 minutes then it open and it is okay for me, but my problem now is if I try to open the reports through ASP.Net website in **Server A**, I got below error after *2 minutes* exactly:   `The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.` 
I tried below solutions with no success :

1. Increase **DatabaseQueryTimeout** in RSReportServer.config for **Server B**.
2. Increase **Connection time-out** in **Server A** from *120* to *240*.
3. executionTimeout="9000" in web.config for **Server A** as below: 
   `<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" maxRequestLength="15360" executionTimeout="9000"></httpRuntime>`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked [IIS Request Timeout on long ASP.NET operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829202/iis-request-timeout-on-long-asp-net-operation)?

Comment: I have checked the link. My execution timeout is already **9000** seconds as mentioned in #3.

Comment: Check RequestTimeout and RequestLength on both servers A and B.

Comment: @drigomed I don't think it's the problem from B as he can download from B  manually.

Comment: Exactly, I can see the reports in **Server B** without any issue, and response of Bad gateway is showing IP address of **Server A**

Comment: Already the **executionTimeout** for both servers is **9000**

Comment: I have checked the link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23508.sql-server-reporting-services-timeout-settings.aspx but all about server B.

Comment: Increase session timeout. Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-web-config