# What happens with SQL operation when IIS Times out in ASP.NET Http Request?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ado.net, httprequest, iis-express

My ASP.NET application is making a database call (stored procedure) to fetch data from SQL server. The number of records to process is large and operation is going to take long time. IIS times out the request after default executionTimeout (110 seconds) which is completely fine in my case. My real question is what happens to the query that is running on the SQL server? Does IIS send any command like abort to sql server to stop the query execution?

Command timeout (300 seconds) set on the stored procedure call from ADO.NET is way more than http request execution timeout (110 seconds).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829202/iis-request-timeout-on-long-asp-net-operation) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31771) but they do not have the answer what I'm looking for.

[This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/khen1234/2005/10/20/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-query-timeout/) explains about how a client sends an abort command to server after command timeout has reached.

The client here is asp.net application in my case. So, IIS has to notify asp.net application that request has reached it max time and then asp.net application signals sql server to abort the executing query. Is that how it works or Am I totally understanding this topic wrong?

This is what I have tried so far running locally using Visual studio 2017 and IIS express: Set `executionTimeout="30"` and `debug = "false"` in `web.config` file. In stored procedure I set `WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00'` for the query to run longer than http request time out. But the web request never timed out. It is waiting for the query to complete.

Comment: I think the simplest way to test this is to add a new table to your database (call it "test" or something like this) and an `insert into` statement that will insert some value into this test table to the end of your long stored procedure (the one you described first, that makes the IIS timeout), and then just run your page, wait for the timeout, and then wait some more and check if the `insert into` command was executed.