# ResT request never returns

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, restsharp

I have installed latest RestSharp NuGet package version (106.3.1) on my C# solution and when I make a request that takes much longer than usual (most of my requests take little time), then the request never returns back to the caller. Although I am working to make this fully async, I am intrigued why this is happening. Please see below a small snipped of my source code.

```
// Private RestClient variable relative to my class.
private RestClient _client;


// Request made to another service inside my method
RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("api/abc/def", Method.POST);
restRequest.AddParameter("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestOp);
restRequest.AddParameter("Application/Json", serializeObject, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var restResponse = this._client.Execute(restRequest);
```

Please notice that I am making at the moment one request at the time. There are no other requests happening in parallel whatsoever but only when the request takes a bit longer than usual, it simply does not return. No timeouts, nothing... Any idea what could this be?

EDIT: When I debug the code on the server side, it returns to the caller with a `return this.Ok(requestOutput);`However, the response never gets received by the caller.

Comment: Is it your API it's calling?  If so, step through the code there and see what's slowing it down.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that the API that gets called returns with an OK and the result. return this.Ok(requestOutput); I will update the post!

Comment: If debugging not helping, then try to watch the traffic via Wireshark.

Comment: I looked into Fiddler and it returns the data but the client never gets it. The data returned is a simply and small object with strings, btw.

Comment: Is your RestClient inside of a ASP.NET-Application? Maybe your execution will be killed by ASP? (standard setting is 20min, termination of ASP is "heavy", it also kills running instances)

Comment: Yeah, it is a ASP.NET Web API. Timeout has increased and the request takes around 7 minutes to execute but maybe it is related to that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829202/iis-request-timeout-on-long-asp-net-operation

Comment: tried above link but didn't work either. My request never returns a timeout but still bumping the value doesn't make the trick